# phpDocumentor goes to PHP, as X goes to Python (Django)

Tags: php, python, django, phpdoc

phpDocumentor goes to PHP, as X goes to Python (Django)

What is the X?

Comment: i would change phpDocumentor to Doxygen ( http://doxygen.org/ ): faster, smaller, more features, ...

Comment: +1 for ax, as it works for all languages.

Answer (score 7):

Or [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), as seen on TV and at [python.org](http://python.org/).

Answer (score 5):

[Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/), [pydoctor](http://codespeak.net/~mwh/pydoctor/) or standard [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html).

Comment: +1 for epydoc, very nice tool

Comment: man you're a saver!!!!!! ALL PHP CODERS MUST USE EPYDOC!!!!! this is exactly what is code documentation about!!!